# netty issue when writeAndFlush called from different InboundChannelHandlerAdapter.channelRead

Tags: sockets, io, netty

I've got an issue, for which I am unable to post full code (sorry), due to security reasons.  The gist of my issue is that I have a ServerBootstrap, created as follows:

```
bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
final ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)                        
.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                                ch.pipeline().addFirst("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 3000));
                                //Adds the MQTT encoder and decoder
                                ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new MyMessageDecoder());
                                ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new MyMessageEncoder());
                                ch.pipeline().addLast(createMyHandler());
                            }
                        }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128).option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                        .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

                // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
                channelFuture = b.bind(listenAddress, listenPort);
```

With createMyHandlerMethod() that basically returns an extended implementation of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`

I also have a "client" listener, that listens for incoming connection requests, and is loaded as follows:

```
    final String host = getHost();
        final int port = getPort();
        nioEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        bootStrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootStrap.group(nioEventLoopGroup);
        bootStrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        bootStrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        bootStrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addFirst("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, getKeepAliveInterval()));
                ch.pipeline().addAfter("idleStateHandler", "idleEventHandler", new MoquetteIdleTimeoutHandler());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new MyMessageDecoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new MyMessageEncoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(MyClientHandler.this);
            }
        })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);

        // Start the client.
        try {
            channelFuture = bootStrap.connect(host, port).sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new MyException(“Exception”, e);
        }
```

Where MyClientHandler is again a subclassed instance of ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.  Everything works fine, I get messages coming in from the "server" adapter, i process them, and send them back on the same context.  And vice-versa for the "client" handler.

The problem happens when I have to (for some messages) proxy them from the server or client handler to other connection.  Again, I am very sorry for not being able to post much code, but the gist of it is that I'm calling from:

```
serverHandler.channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
     if (msg instanceof myProxyingMessage) {
        if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
             ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(someOtherMessage);
             **getClientHandler().writeAndFlush(myProxyingMessage);**
        }
     }
}
```

Now here's the problem:  the bolded (client) writeAndFlush - never actually writes the message bytes, it doesn't throw any errors.  The ChannelFuture returns all false (success, cancelled, done).  And if I sync on it, eventually it times out for other reasons (connection timeout set within my code).

I know I haven't posted all of my code, but I'm hoping that someone has some tips and/or pointers for how to isolate the problem of WHY it is not writing to the client context.  I'm not a Netty expert by any stretch, and most of this code was written by someone else.  They are both subclassing `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`

Feel free to ask any questions if you have any.

*****EDIT*********
I tried to proxy the request back to a DIFFERENT context/channel (ie, the client channel) using the following test code:

```
public void proxyPubRec(int messageId) throws MQTTException {
        logger.log(logLevel, "proxying PUBREC to context:  " + debugContext());
        PubRecMessage pubRecMessage = new PubRecMessage();
        pubRecMessage.setMessageID(messageId);
        pubRecMessage.setRemainingLength(2);
        logger.log(logLevel, "pipeline writable flag:  " + ctx.pipeline().channel().isWritable());
        MyMQTTEncoder encoder = new MyMQTTEncoder();

        ByteBuf buff = null;
        try {
            buff = encoder.encode(pubRecMessage);
            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buff);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "unable to encode PUBREC");
        } finally {
            if (buff != null) {
                buff.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyMQTTEncoder extends MQTTEncoder {
        public ByteBuf encode(AbstractMessage msg) {
            PooledByteBufAllocator allocator = new PooledByteBufAllocator();
            ByteBuf buf = allocator.buffer();
            try {
                super.encode(ctx, msg, buf);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "unable to encode PUBREC, " + t.getMessage());
            }
            return buf;
        }
    }
```

But the above at line:  `ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buff)` is NOT writing to the other channel - any tips/tricks on debugging this sort of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this turned out to be a threading issue.  One of my threads was blocked/waiting while other threads were writing to the context and because of this, the writes were buffered and not sent, even with a flush.  Problem solved!

Essentially, I put the first message code in an Runnable/Executor thread, which allowed it to run separately so that the second write/response was able to write to the context.  There are still potentially some issues with this (in terms of message ordering), but this is not on topic for the original question.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

`someOtherMessage` has to be `ByteBuf`.

So, take this :

```
serverHandler.channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
     if (msg instanceof myProxyingMessage) {
        if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
             ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(someOtherMessage);
             **getClientHandler().writeAndFlush(myProxyingMessage);**
        }
     }
}
```

... and replace it with this :

```
serverHandler.channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
     if (msg instanceof myProxyingMessage) {
        if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
             ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(ByteBuf);
             **getClientHandler().writeAndFlush(myProxyingMessage);**
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I believe that in this case the ByteBuf is not really needed, since I have a Decoder/Encoder that takes care of the byte handling.  For example, MQTTDecoder/MQTTEncoder.  I'm not 100% sure, but this issue seems to be something with the way netty handles channel reads/writes - I am writing to a _different_context after reading from the server context in this case, and the write never pushes/flushes the content for whatever reason.   I don't know why.

Comment: I tried it - please see my edit above - it didn't work :( I was hopeful though....

Comment: Can you provide ByteBuf code which u used to convert `someOtherMessage`

Comment: Actually, this turned out to be a threading issue.  One of my threads was blocked/waiting while other threads were writing to the context and because of this, the writes were buffered and not sent, even with a flush.  Problem solved!  :)